# Generate EAN code for products

Tags: attributes, amazon-web-services, amazon, m2e

How could I generate EAN code for existing products and also how could I create automatically this EAN when adding a new product?

On what is this EAN code based on?

Comment: you cam look at this http://www.boostmyshop.com/english/barcode-label.html

Comment: @AhmedElAwadi : Thank you! I looked over it but from description it does not seem to create EAN for already existing products

Comment: look also at this https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-ean-generator, the original post is in here http://blog.gaiterjones.com/generate-ean-barcodes-for-all-magento-products-magento-ean-barcode-generator/

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik either a product has an EAN or not. You can not just create an EAN. [You have to get EANs, so you can put them on your products](http://www.issn.org/understanding-the-issn/issn-uses/identification-with-the-ean-13-barcode/), you can do [this here](http://www.issn.org/services/requesting-an-issn/?lang=en).